# Can we record browser screen with AWS Kinesis video streams with WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, webrtc, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

Can we send [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) directly to Kinesis Streams with WebRTC? From the example [code](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-js/blob/master/examples/master.js#L111) it looks like we can, I'm completely lost here. If we can send [getDisplayMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia) to Kinesis, will we be able to persist the recording to S3, if so, how do we do that?

Answer (score 0):

kinesis video stream currently dont support persisting WebRTC streams from the browser. You can consider storing the media streams into file and persist them using the producer sdk https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp.